# Python 3 absolute imports not working after setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I have a Python 3 project I wanted to release. Here is the structure:

```
README.rst
setup.cfg
setup.py
projectname
├── __init__.py
├── __main__.py
├── file1.py
└── file2.py
```

In my setup.py I have the usual info (name, description etc.) and two relevant lines are:

```
packages=find_packages(),
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'project-name=projectname.__main__:main',
    ],
},
```

In my `__main__.py`, I do the following imports:

```
from file1 import a
from file2 import b
```

My project works fine when running `__main__.py` in the terminal normally:

```
python3 __main__.py
```

However, after running setup.py:

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

and running:

```
project-name
```

I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'file1'
```

What is strange is that if I do explicit relative imports instead:

```
from .file1 import a
from .file2 import b
```

This will work for the installed package but NOT when running `__main__.py` normally in the terminal where I will get the following error:

```
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

I am completely lost here, can anybody shed some light? I have been reading on imports in Python 3 and nothing has helped me yet. Any help would be much appreciated. Please let me know if addition information is required. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using py2exe?

Comment: Try this: Move your `__main__.py` into the root folder. Then make the relative imports in `__init__.py`. In `__main__.py`, you import like `import a`.